# Opera wallet web3 problems

Tags: web3js, wallets, dapps

I am writing a Dapp. I'm not an expert. It works perfectly on Edge, Firefox, and Chrome (with MetaMask). But I get the following error on Opera when the cryptowallet is on but not synced:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code": -32503,
    "message": "wallet address undefined"
  },
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

If I refresh the page, the error dissapears.

My web3.js component is as follows:

```
<pre>
import Web3 from 'web3';

let web3;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.web3 !== undefined) {

  const getProvider = async () => {
  await window.web3.currentProvider.enable();
  };
  getProvider();

  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
  window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;  
} else {
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    '//rinkeby.infura.io/v3/key'
  );
  web3 = new Web3(provider);
}
</pre>
```

I am using:

```
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.1",
    "solc": "^0.5.11",
    "tinify": "^1.6.0-beta.2",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "web3": "^1.2.4"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  We are having a lot of trouble having a consistent connection to Opera as well

Comment: Same here, nearly a year later. What's up Opera?

Answer (score 0):

Well i know its been a while, but i was having a similar problem, then i figure out that if i disable opera's cryprocurrency wallet, metamask works just fine. Just because of this i wasn't able to use eth network on some certain moments which i could benefit a lot.